# Count rows in DataFrame with column value between two columns of current row. Add as column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a table with the following columns:

```
| user| event_start         | event_end           | show_start          | show_end            | show_name  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 286 | 2018-06-12 00:00:19 | 2018-06-12 00:00:48 | 2018-06-12 00:00:00 | 2018-06-12 01:00:00 | foo        |
| 287 | 2018-06-12 00:00:45 | 2018-06-12 00:00:53 | 2018-06-12 00:00:00 | 2018-06-12 01:00:00 | foo        |
| 288 | 2018-06-12 00:00:47 | 2018-06-12 00:00:58 | 2018-06-12 00:00:00 | 2018-06-12 02:00:00 | bar        |
...
```

How can I add a new column with the count of distinct users across the table such that their `event_start` value lies in between this row's `show_start` and `show_end`?

Such that I am left with a table like the following:

```
| user| event_start         | event_end           | show_start          | show_end            | show_name  | active_users |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 286 | 2018-06-12 00:00:19 | 2018-06-12 00:00:48 | 2018-06-12 00:00:00 | 2018-06-12 01:00:00 | foo        | 18           |
| 287 | 2018-06-12 00:00:45 | 2018-06-12 00:00:53 | 2018-06-12 00:00:00 | 2018-06-12 01:00:00 | foo        | 18           |
| 288 | 2018-06-12 00:00:47 | 2018-06-12 00:00:58 | 2018-06-12 00:00:00 | 2018-06-12 02:00:00 | bar        | 31           |
...
```

This will be used, down the road, to calculate the share of users watching each show versus the share of active users.

I have a gut feeling I might need window functions, but I can't quite start structuring the operations needed.

Comment: yes a window function should do the trick but what have you tried

Answer (score 2):

From the clarified requirement in the comments section, it looks like a full-dataframe lookup of active users for every distinct show is required.  This could be expensive especially if there are many distinct shows.  Assuming the number of distinct shows isn't too big (i.e. small enough to be `collect`-ed), here is one approach:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import java.sql.Timestamp

val df = Seq(
  (286, Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 00:00:19"), Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 00:00:48"),
        Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 00:00:00"), Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 01:00:00"), "foo"),
  (287, Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 00:00:45"), Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 00:00:53"),
        Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 00:00:00"), Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 01:00:00"), "foo"),
  (288, Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 00:00:47"), Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 00:00:58"),
        Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 00:00:00"), Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 02:00:00"), "bar"),
  (301, Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 03:00:15"), Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 03:00:45"),
        Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 00:00:00"), Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 02:00:00"), "bar"),
  (302, Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 00:00:15"), Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 00:00:30"),
        Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 00:00:00"), Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 02:00:00"), "bar"),
  (302, Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 01:00:20"), Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 01:00:50"),
        Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 00:00:00"), Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 02:00:00"), "bar"),
  (303, Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 01:00:30"), Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 01:00:45"),
        Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 02:00:00"), Timestamp.valueOf("2018-06-12 03:00:00"), "gee")
).toDF("user", "event_start", "event_end", "show_start", "show_end", "show_name")

df.show
// +----+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+
// |user|        event_start|          event_end|         show_start|           show_end|show_name|
// +----+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+
// | 286|2018-06-12 00:00:19|2018-06-12 00:00:48|2018-06-12 00:00:00|2018-06-12 01:00:00|      foo|
// | 287|2018-06-12 00:00:45|2018-06-12 00:00:53|2018-06-12 00:00:00|2018-06-12 01:00:00|      foo|
// | 288|2018-06-12 00:00:47|2018-06-12 00:00:58|2018-06-12 00:00:00|2018-06-12 02:00:00|      bar|
// | 301|2018-06-12 03:00:15|2018-06-12 03:00:45|2018-06-12 00:00:00|2018-06-12 02:00:00|      bar|
// | 302|2018-06-12 00:00:15|2018-06-12 00:00:30|2018-06-12 00:00:00|2018-06-12 02:00:00|      bar|
// | 302|2018-06-12 01:00:20|2018-06-12 01:00:50|2018-06-12 00:00:00|2018-06-12 02:00:00|      bar|
// | 303|2018-06-12 01:00:30|2018-06-12 01:00:45|2018-06-12 02:00:00|2018-06-12 03:00:00|      gee|
// +----+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+

val showList = df.select($"show_name", $"show_start", $"show_end").
  distinct.collect

val showsListNew = showList.map( row => {
    val distinctCount = df.select(countDistinct(when($"event_start".between(
        row.getTimestamp(1), row.getTimestamp(2)
      ), $"user"))
    ).head.getLong(0)

    (row.getString(0), row.getTimestamp(1), row.getTimestamp(2), distinctCount)
  }
)
// showsListNew: Array[(String, java.sql.Timestamp, java.sql.Timestamp, Long)] = Array(
//   (gee, 2018-06-12 02:00:00.0, 2018-06-12 03:00:00.0, 0),
//   (bar, 2018-06-12 00:00:00.0, 2018-06-12 02:00:00.0, 5),
//   (foo, 2018-06-12 00:00:00.0, 2018-06-12 01:00:00.0, 4)
// )

val showDF = sc.parallelize(showsListNew).toDF("show_name", "show_start", "show_end", "active_users")

df.join(showDF, Seq("show_name", "show_start", "show_end")).
  show
// +---------+-------------------+-------------------+----+-------------------+-------------------+------------+
// |show_name|         show_start|           show_end|user|        event_start|          event_end|active_users|
// +---------+-------------------+-------------------+----+-------------------+-------------------+------------+
// |      gee|2018-06-12 02:00:00|2018-06-12 03:00:00| 303|2018-06-12 01:00:30|2018-06-12 01:00:45|           0|
// |      bar|2018-06-12 00:00:00|2018-06-12 02:00:00| 302|2018-06-12 01:00:20|2018-06-12 01:00:50|           5|
// |      bar|2018-06-12 00:00:00|2018-06-12 02:00:00| 302|2018-06-12 00:00:15|2018-06-12 00:00:30|           5|
// |      bar|2018-06-12 00:00:00|2018-06-12 02:00:00| 301|2018-06-12 03:00:15|2018-06-12 03:00:45|           5|
// |      bar|2018-06-12 00:00:00|2018-06-12 02:00:00| 288|2018-06-12 00:00:47|2018-06-12 00:00:58|           5|
// |      foo|2018-06-12 00:00:00|2018-06-12 01:00:00| 287|2018-06-12 00:00:45|2018-06-12 00:00:53|           4|
// |      foo|2018-06-12 00:00:00|2018-06-12 01:00:00| 286|2018-06-12 00:00:19|2018-06-12 00:00:48|           4|
// +---------+-------------------+-------------------+----+-------------------+-------------------+------------+
```

Comment: This seems to work, unfortunately, the data I am working with right now is so big I really can't say if the results are reasonable just by looking at them; how can I be sure that the above code is counting `event_starts` (over all rows) lying between this row's `show_start` and `show_end`?
Also, how can I accommodate the condition of summing unique `user` values?

Comment: @alonsos: This looks like it should work as long as the `show_name` column is unique (if not, simply add `show_start` to `Window.partitionBy()`).

Comment: I added both `show_start` and `show_end` to `partitionBy()` and it looks like it works. The only problem being that since I have multiple events for each user, the above is summing over all events and, for certain shows, `active_users` is bigger than the sum of distinct users across the database.

Comment: @alonso s, please see expanded answer.

Comment: @LeoC I checked the expanded answer. Knowing `collect_set` and `size` exist certainly helps me. There is one problem with the calculation of the `active_users` column: is should have value `4` across all rows since during the time interval specified by `show_start` and `show_end` we had `4` events (by users `288`, `302`, `287` and `286`). What I want is for the aggregation to count all event occurrences (across all rows) during the that row's show duration.

Comment: @alonso s, the clarified requirement requires a vastly different approach.  I've revised the answer with a slightly more arbitrary sample dataset.